# Specify method's type without converting the method to property

Tags: typescript, types

Let's say, I have a method that delegates its functionality to some method from external library, and I have a type for that external method, e.g. `LibDoStuffMethodType`.

```
class MyApp {
  doStuff(args) {
     // delegate to external library's lib.doStuff
  }
}
```

Now, how do I specify the type for my method `MyApp.doStuff()`? Naturally, I can make the `doStuff()` a property of MyApp:

```
class MyApp {
  doStuff: LibDoStuffMethodType
}
```

But this is undesirable for multiple reasons (one of those is the IntelliSense support, we'd rather see in the IntelliSense suggestions that `doStuff()` is an actual method, not a property, methods and properties are colored and marked differently).

So, the question is: is there *any* way to keep the method as method, but somehow specify its full type `LibDoStuffMethodType`?

Comment: Except for the different icon there should be no functional differences between the two

Comment: Indeed,but still this is quite confusing for junior devs, they are looking for the method but they see the property.

Comment: Yeah, I get the frustration, and share it. For mapped types for example the method / function field distinction is lost as well for example. I don't think there is a way around the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an existing suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#22063](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063) to allow function statements (and presumably method definitions) to be typed using a function/callable type alias or interface.  Doesn't look like there's much traction there, but if you believe you have a strong use case, you might want to go there and give it a  or comment.

---

In the absence of that feature, what if you were to create an interface that your class needs to implement, like this?

```
type LibDoStuffMethodType = (x: string, y: number) => boolean
interface DoStuffMethod { doStuff: LibDoStuffMethodType };

class MyApp implements DoStuffMethod {
  doStuff(a: string, b: number) {
    return true;
    // delegate to external library's lib.doStuff
  }
}
declare const myApp: MyApp;
myApp.doStuff; // looks like a method now
```

The class `MyApp` now has a bona fide method named `doStuff`, but it is constrained to be of type `LibDoStuffMethodType`!

---

This works as far as it goes, but I suspect you'll be unhappy that you need to strongly type the method's parameters and return type.  It would be great if these would be automatically inferred from the interface `DoStuffMethod`, but unfortunately this is not currently possible ([see microsoft/TypeScript#1373](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373)).  Which means that I expect any straightforward solution to your problem will require some duplication.

Are there ways around this?  Well, if `LibDoStuffMethodType` is a single (no overloads) specific (no generics) function type, you can use [the `Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [the `ReturnType<T>` utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) to annotate the parameter list and return type programmatically:

```
class MyApp implements DoStuffMethod {
  doStuff(...args: Parameters<LibDoStuffMethodType>): ReturnType<LibDpStuffMethodType> {
    return true;
    // delegate to external library's lib.doStuff
  }
}
```

That is DRYer, but there are so many caveats that I don't know if it's a good fit for you. I don't know if there are other workarounds, but I suspect they will all have similar issues.

That's the closest I can get.