# How to share a TypeScript function definition between two classes?

Tags: typescript, .d.ts

When declaring a class in a TypeScript Declaration File (`.d.ts`), you can add a function to it like so:

```
declare class Foo {
  myFunction (arg1: number, arg2: string): void;
}
```

But what if you want to have a function with the same signature in another class? You could of course just copy and paste the line, but you could also define it using `type` and reuse that type multiple times:

```
declare class Foo {
  myFunction: MyFunctionFn;
}

declare class Bar {
  myFunction: MyFunctionFn;
}

type MyFunctionFn = (arg1: number, arg2: string) => void;
```

The problem with that is how VS Code and other editors render the function during auto-complete. Below is an example showing the following declaration:

```
declare class Foo {
  sharedFn: SharedFn;
  inlineFn (arg1: number, arg2: string): void; 
}

type SharedFn = (arg1: number, arg2: string) => void;
```

[image]

As you can see, the `inlineFn` is shown correctly as a method, whereas the `sharedFn` is shown as a property (that in this case just happen to be assigned a value of function).

Is there a way in TypeScript to have it show up as a proper method, but still share the function signature with other classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify method's type without converting the method to property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207348/specify-methods-type-without-converting-the-method-to-property/51212521#51212521)

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect solution for you.  Here's a middle-of-the-road solution which is less repetitive than typing out all the parameters themselves, but not as nice as the desired method annotation:

```
type MyFunctionFn = (arg1: number, arg2: string) => void;

declare class Foo {
  myFunction(...args: Parameters<MyFunctionFn>): ReturnType<MyFunctionFn>;
}

declare class Bar {
  myFunction(...args: Parameters<MyFunctionFn>): ReturnType<MyFunctionFn>;
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207348/specify-methods-type-without-converting-the-method-to-property/51212521#51212521) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to create a `.d.ts` file. If you work with classes your types will automatically be declared.

If you want classes to share a method signature you can use an interface. Now you will get better IntelliSense:

```
interface Foo {
    myFunction: (arg1: number, arg2: string) => void;
}

class Bar implements Foo {
    myFunction(arg1: number, arg2: string){

    }
}

let c = new Bar()
c.myFunction(2, "hi")
```

[image]

Comment: Manually creating `.d.ts` files are useful if you're adding types to a module that is coded in JavaScript instead of TypeScript

Comment: Implementing interfaces is great when coding TypeScript natively where you need to code the body of the function you're implementing from the interface. But in this case I'm adding types to a JavaScript module and my goal is to not have to write the method twice, in which case implementing an interface actually forces me to type out the method signature N+1 times.