# How to use TypeScript to allow different types as function parameters when the logic is shared?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to deduplicate the functions below if possible, by making a function that can work with either TypeA or TypeB or TypeC even.

```ts
export const countTypeAs = (): ((
    value: [string, TypeA[] | undefined],
    index: number,
    array: [string, TypeA[] | undefined][]
) => [string, number | undefined]) => {
    return ([key, TypeAs]) => // counting logic
};

export const countTypeBs = (): ((
    value: [string, TypeB[] | undefined],
    index: number,
    array: [string, TypeB[] | undefined][]
) => [string, number | undefined]) => {
    return ([key, TypeBs]) => // same counting logic
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure trying to remove duplication there is a good idea. You could follow the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55208211/how-to-share-a-typescript-function-definition-between-two-classes except that your function would need generics so that TypeA and TypeB could be passed in.

Comment: Your example doesn't work, you're trying to `([key, TypeBs])` which is invalid since `TypeBs` is not value, it's a type. From your example, it looks like it's the same logic in both? So why have two functions? Make it just one function
`countTypeBs = (): ((value: [string, TypeB[] || TypeA[] | undefined],index: number, array: [string, TypeB[] | TypeA[] | undefined][]) => ...` Please improve your example since we can't tell what you're actually trying to do. It's the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I doubt your code is a [mre].  I don't understand why you want your functions to require `index` and `array` inputs when you just throw them away (if you're passing it to `map` you can just forget those in your definition); I don't understand why your function a no-arg thunk that returns the function you care about. I don't understand why you've left out the counting logic which is likely to be one line of code. Could you fix these? I think you want [the code shown here](https://tsplay.dev/Wyo7nN) as your answer, but it would be nice not to have to fix unrelated issues to get there.