# Declare a class function member with an external type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use an existing function definition as a defintion for a class's function.
Ex:

`type definition = (param: string) => void`

Then I'd like to declare a class that have this function:

```
class C {
   fnct(param) {
   }
}
```

How to tell typescript that `fnct` is of type `definition` ?

I don't wan't to declare fnct as a member like this :

```
class C {
   fnct: definition = (param) => {
   }
}
```

Because I need to apply an annotation which is a MethodDecorator and it doesnt wan't to apply to a lambda declared as a member.

I tried to [make an interface and make my class implement it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAJhBmBLAdo4iD2yoF4oAowBDAJyIFsAuKAZ2BJQHMBKXAPigDcNEYAoPimAQS8IgGNoASSgBvPlEXxk44NThJU6LHwC%20A8QBsiNGlADCUROTCGI5CMmBmZ8xVGWrCpCq3kLFfV0gA) :

```
interface I {
   fnct: definition
}

class C implements I {
   fnct() {

   }
}
```

but in this case, fnct does not take the type from the interface.

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: I wish there were something better than [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51207348/specify-methods-type-without-converting-the-method-to-property) but things are more or less the same since 2018, unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for your reply @jcalz. I wish too :(